# fgets() does not read the whole file

Tags: c, windows, winapi, stdio

I'm writing a program that basically searches a directory and all its sub-directories for duplicate files. I have refined both the question and the code according to your suggestions (functions that needed to return a default value have been fixed to do so) so here it goes...

Here is the code of the comparing functions:

```
int compare()
{
    int a, b;
    unsigned char byte1, byte2;

    while(1)
    {
        a = fread(&byte1, 1, 1, file1);
        b = fread(&byte2, 1, 1, file2);
        if(a == 0 && b == 0) break;
        if(a != b) return 1;
        if(byte2 != byte1) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void startCompare()
{
    char path1[1000], path2[1000];
    FILE *reference = fopen("list.comp", "r");
    FILE *other = fopen("list2.comp", "r");
    int i, flag, j;
    i = 0;

    while(fgets(path1, 1000, reference))
    {
        flag = 0;
        strtok(path1, "\n");  
        openFile1(path1);
        for(j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            fgets(path2, 1000, other);
        }
        while(fgets(path2, 1000, other))
        {
            strtok(path2, "\n");
            openFile2(path2);
            if(!compare())
            {
                printf("Checking: %s vs. %s --> DUPLICATE\n", path1, path2);
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Checking: %s vs. %s --> DIFFERENT\n", path1, path2);
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            printf("Will be deleted.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

(The startCompare() function is called first)

Now, the directory itself has these files:

- bloblo
- bloblo/frofo
- bloblo/frofo/New Folder
- bloblo/frofo/New Folder (2)
- bloblo/frofo/New Folder (2)/New Folder (3)
- bloblo/frofo/New Folder (2)/New Folder (3)/New Text Document.txt
- bloblo/frofo/New Folder (2)/New Folder (3)/Untitled4
- 0.comp
- 1.comp
- 2.comp
- 3.comp
- 4.comp
- 5.comp
- 11.comp
- 100.comp
- duplicate_delete.dev
- duplicate_delete.exe
- duplicate_delete.layout
- list.comp
- list2.comp
- main.c
- main.o
- Makefile.win
- Untitled5.c
- Untitled5.exe

The output is:

```
Checking: 0.comp vs. 1.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 100.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 11.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 2.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 3.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 4.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. 5.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. duplicate_delete.dev --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. duplicate_delete.exe --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. duplicate_delete.layout --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. list.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. list2.comp --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. main.c --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. main.o --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. Makefile.win --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. Untitled5.c --> DIFFERENT
Checking: 0.comp vs. Untitled5.exe --> DIFFERENT
```

With return code 0.

While what it should be printing is every file being checked with each other and finding that the files 100.comp and 11.comp are a duplicate of each other and the other files unique. So basically, why does it stop there? Why doesn't it continue to check? Is there any way this can be solved?

Comment: Please clarify which files you have (the formatting of your list got messed up), what the expected output is, and what output you get. Please try removing files that are not needed to demonstrate the problem (reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might also help). Also, please ask a question about *one* version of your code - either with or without `fclose` - this will reduce confusion.

Comment: `compare` uses `feof` wrong and lacks a return statement at the end.

Comment: First of all make sure all your functions that return a value DO return a value. `main` is declared as returning `int`, but does not return nothing.  `openFile1` returns 0 when you cannot open the file, but returns garbage from the stack when you can. The same for `openFile2`. What does return `compare` when all the ifs statements are not true? Garbage...

Comment: Please note that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is by definition **1**.

Comment: Your recent edit has confused the entire post.  Recommend 1) Revert post to before "refined both the question and the code according to your suggestions" 2) Accept @Weather Vane 3) Post a _new_ question that refers to this one 4) Make certain your new post is completely compilable, Shows the remaining problem with minimum lines of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question you actually asked (why doesn't it compare all pairs of files):

Your program first reads the first line from `list.comp`. Then, it reads each line from `list2.comp` and compares the files.

Then, it reads the next line from `list.comp`, and tries to compare it with all the files from `list2.comp` again. But it's already at the end of `list2.comp`, so it doesn't read any more filenames from `list2.comp`.

You could use `rewind(other);` to "rewind" back to the beginning of `list2.comp`, so you can read the filenames again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will answer your TLDR question and code, but this is too much for a comment.

Your function `compare()` never returns `0`, if you had enabled and taken notice of compiler warnings, you would have known this. The function also uses the dreaded `feof()`. See [*why `feof()` is wrong*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

I suggest replacing this

```
int compare()
{
    while(!feof(file1))
    {
        fread(&byte1, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file1);
        fread(&byte2, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file2);
        if(byte2 != byte1) return 1;
    }
    if(feof(file1) && (!feof(file2))) return 1;
    if(feof(file2) && (!feof(file1))) return 1;
}
```

with this, because checking the amount of data read by `fread()` is the way to test for end of file.

```
int compare()
// return 0 if files are the same
// *** always include a comment to tell you what the function does / returns ***
{
    size_t read1, read2;
    while(1) {
        read1 = fread(&byte1, 1, 1, file1);
        read2 = fread(&byte2, 1, 1, file2);
        if (read1==0 && read2==0)
            break;             // success: both files ended
        if (read1 != read2)
            return 1;          // bad: one of them read, other didn't
        if (byte2 != byte1)
            return 1;          // bad: files read different data
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and note that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is quite unnecessary, it is 1.

I would also have put `byte1` and `byte2` as local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but if you are searching for duplicate files, you are using an inefficient approach.  It's better to run **md5sum(1)** on them and sort the listing produced.  Then, you'll compare one line with the next for equal md5 values.  In case you don't trust **md5sum(1)** (somebody says that different files can give the same checksum), you can just compare the file contents (but only on the already matching md5 checksums).  This is, by far, much more efficient than your approach.  It can be solved with:

```
find <dir> -type f -name "glob_pattern" -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort >files.md5sum
```

then, edit the file `files.md5sum` and search for `/^\([0-9a-f]*\) .*\n\1/` pattern to get the repeated md5's.  You'll get even multiple repetitions of the same file.

### Note

Take care that empty files have all the same MD5 checksum and all of them compare equal.  You'll get this also in your listing.